# SQL Query for Updating value from other table values for N records

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I have some wrong entries in number column of history table, So I have to take the number column value from motorvehicle table and update in history table.The below query i am using for update,

```
UPDATE history
   SET history.number = (SELECT motorvehicle.number
                                   FROM motorvehicle
                                   WHERE motorvehicle.FK_ID = history.FK_ID
                                   AND   history.DATE = '2018-05-08'
                                   AND   history.state = 35 fetch first 1000 rows only)
```

When i run this query, i am getting error like "[21000] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0811N: The result of a scalar fullselect, the SELECT INTO statement, or the VALUES INTO statement consists of more than one row".

If i remove the fetch first 1000 rows only from the query , it is not giving any syntax error but it fails due to transaction log is full.

My DB is Db2-LUW V10.5 and running in Linux server.

Can anyone please help me to overcome this issue? If the above query is not the correct way of updating can u please suggest some new query based on my situation?

Comment: Seems like motorvehicle contains at least a few rows with the same FK_ID value. Those history.date and history.state conditions in the subquery look strange.

Comment: There are some predicates wrong. How is the relationship defined and how do you identify the wrong numbers?

Comment: @jarlh  history.number values are updated wrongly on 2018-05-08 for the records which have history.state = 35. Thats why i have included this condition in subquery. I have checked in the motorvehicle table, there are no duplicates for the FK_ID.

Comment: Add some sample table data, both before and after update versions. As formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue with oracle and SQL developer because the sub query returns more than one record for history. Ex: for ID 1 there is exactly 1 match in history so it worked fine but for ID 2500 the query matched multiple records which throw exception in the mid of the way. To sort this out I needed to add more specification conditions and rownum =1 in the sub query.

In your case fetch first 1000 rows only : it should be 1.

Comment: thanks for your response. Now what should i modify in my query..Should I change the "fetch first 1000 rows only" to "fetch first 1 rows only"..Then it will return only one row right

Comment: Yes :) and if oracle u can use rownum = 1 .  This will make sure that max 1 record is returned . For more safety u need to add 1 more check that record exists in history table. Dont forget to mark the ans :))